# Minimum Transferrable Energy

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation

Purest form of energy is Light [EM Waves], basically a photon, if we talk in terms of particles.

So, what is the minimum amount of energy that can be transferred to any particle using a photon ?

To develop on this, I thought about electron of Hydrogen atom. Minimum energy a photon could give this electron is the value which will be helpful for electron to get excited to next level. Further, we can also think a photon can transfer some energy to a particle in direct collision too, but the issues in this thought I faced were -

1. What could be minimum energy a particle can accept if it is at rest and it is isolated ?
2. If there is no threshold for a particle to accept energy, then what could be the minimum energy a photon could possess to successfully collide and transfer energy to the particle ?

I am looking forward to knowing if there is limit in energy transfer at any stage or not.

Answer (score 1):

In the quantum mechanical modeling of electron photon interactions using Quantum ElectroDynamics there is only the limit of measuring/knowing within errors the [four momenta](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) of the scattering of an electron with a photon. [Example](https://www.personal.soton.ac.uk/ab1u06/teaching/qft/qft1/christmas_problems/2014/xmas_problem_solution.pdf) of how to calculate Compton scattering in QED.No minimum transfer in principle.

The [Compton scattering formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering#Derivation_of_the_scattering_formula) was originally derived by Compton using conservation laws , but the theoretical model rests on QED. The same is true for all the other specialized formulas [describing photon electron interactions](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=feynman%20diagram%20electron%20photon%20scattering) .

Answer (score 1):

Energy in bound systems becomes quantized, but in free systems it is not. Therefore, there is no minimum energy that needs to be transferred to a free particle.

However, as the energy of a photon gets lower, its wavelength will get longer. As the wavelength gets longer, less of it will overlap with the scatter target. Therefore, the probability for an interaction will go down. Asymptotically, as the energy goes to zero, the interaction probability goes to zero too. Of course you get the same conclusion from Heisenberg's uncertainty relation: as the energy difference goes to zero, you need to wait infinitely long. This doesn't give a hard threshold, but, depending on the scenario, one could argue that the wavelength corresponding to the minimum energy needs to be larger than the size of your particle, give or take.